# continuous extension problem

Tags: continuity

I was practicing on some exercises because I have quiz tomorrow, and I got stuck at this exercise, so I wish that someone would help me.
here is the exercise.

Given

$$g(x) = \frac{x^2 -16}{x-4}$$

1)Is $g$ continuous at $x=4$? Justify.
2)Does $g$ have a continuous extension at $x=4$? If yes, give this extension.

The first question is easy for me. I have to find that 
$$\lim_{x\to 4^+} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 4^-} g(x) = g(4)$$

But my problem  is the 2nd question because I don't know what continuous extension means and I don't know how to find it either.

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: No, your answer to 1) is wrong. $g(4)$ is not even defined.

Comment: Zhw. I didn't calculated  it but i am just saying  how  it could  be done and thanks  because  u pointed  that  out to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $g:D\to Y$ is a function from a set $D\subset X$ to another set $Y$. Then a continuous extension of $g$ is a function $h : X\to Y$ such that $g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in D$ and $h$ is continuous. A continuous extension at a point, say $x=4$ means that point is in $X$. I.e. we want the continuous extension to be defined at that point (in this case 4).

In this case how you would find it is just notice that $$\frac{x^2-16}{x-4}=\frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{x-4}.$$ whenever $x\ne 4$, we can cancel and then we have $$\require{cancel} g(x)=\frac{\cancel{(x-4)}(x+4)}{\cancel{x-4}}=x+4.$$ So $x+4$ is a continuous extension, since it agrees with the original function wherever $x-4 \ne 0$. i.e. everywhere except $4$ and the original function was not defined there anyway, and $x+4$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Jgon,thanks for your answer.  I understand what  u mean. i have to find another equation that isn't discontinuous  at x=4  .. but i didn't  understand  how  u came out with the continuous  extension  equation  x+4 is there any steps that  i have to follow  ? And sorry for my bad english  :p

Comment: Oh sorry, let me expand